# What is the use of route-target without export/import?

Tags: bgp, vrf

On my router, I can configure the following:
[image: route-target]

I canont find any information regarding the use of the "route-target ASN:nn" command. I know what route-target import/export allows me to do, but what use does it have if you only specify the community ?

Comment: Please, never us an image for text. Simply copy the text, and paste it into your question using the Preformatted-text option (`{}`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misreading the help prompt.  The full command is `route-target aa:bb [import|export|both]`  If you enter just `route-target aa:bb` it will be rejected as an incomplete command.

Comment: duh, no doubt I couldn't find anything. Thanks